# Traditional way of doing asnyc method in javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I was searching online on how we create the traditional way of doing `async` function in Javascript but it wasn't available. I have implemented a `promise` function in my program, however the software that I am using (tableu) to create all custom styling does not support ES5-ES8 and `async` functions, as this will throw an error, so I was wondering if this is possible.

```js
function promise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 500);
  })
}

async function result() {
  await promise();
}

result().then(render => {
  customStyle()
});
```

All of my code shown is working fine. I'm wondering how can I convert this to the old way of doing `async` functions. Is this possible or is it only available in ES8?

Comment: `async`/`await` is just syntactic sugar. The *old fashioned* way was using callbacks and the reason why Promises and async/await were introduced were simply to make code more readable. JavaScript has always been asynchronous to my understanding, and (in the context of browsers) prioritizing certain events and calls over others in the stack. So what you're looking for is just the concept of callbacks. See this article: [Callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function)

Comment: You might want to use Babel to transpile your code into es5 before running it in your runtime. 

Or just write your code es5 style.

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are the non-Promise or async/await way of doing this, and are basically how those things work under the hood.

Here's a simple example by modifying your snippet:

```
function promise(callback) {
    setTimeout(() => callback(), 500);
}

function result() {
    promise(callback);
}

function callback() {
    customStyle();
};
```

Instead of `result` being an async function that you can await elsewhere in your code, it could also take a callback argument, like `promise`, that you would pass it when it's invoked. The implementation of that callback function would be like the `then` of an actual Promise.

Now you can see why the Promise API and async/await were such nice improvements to the spec.

Answer (score 0):

To use promises the tradicional way, you have to replace the await and use `.then(()=> ...)`. I'll try to show a snippet here to help you to understood.

The code that you have shown does not need the async or await, it goes well like that

```js
function promise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('resolved')
      resolve()
    }, 500);
  })
}

promise().then(render => {
  customStyle()
});
```

Here i'll show you a code that have a good use of it and then I'll convert it:

```js
function callSomeService() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('service whas called')
      resolve({ idOfSomething: 1 })
    }, 2000);
  })
}

function callAnotherServiceUsingTheDataOfThePreviousCall(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('service whas called with', data)
      resolve(['potato 1', 'potato 2', 'potato 3'])
    }, 2000);
  })
}

async function result() {
  const serviceResponse = await callSomeService();
  const arrayOfPotatos = await callAnotherServiceUsingTheDataOfThePreviousCall(serviceResponse);
  
  return arrayOfPotatos.map((potato, index) => `${index} - ${potato}`)
}

result().then(arrayOfPotatos => {
  arrayOfPotatos.forEach(potato => console.log(potato))
});
```

Now I'll convert it to not use async or await, but still using promises.

```js
function callSomeService() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('service whas called')
      resolve({ idOfSomething: 1 })
    }, 2000)
  })
}

function callAnotherServiceUsingTheDataOfThePreviousCall(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('service whas called with', data)
      resolve(['potato 1', 'potato 2', 'potato 3'])
    }, 2000)
  })
}

function result() {
  return callSomeService().then(serviceResponse => {
    return callAnotherServiceUsingTheDataOfThePreviousCall(
      serviceResponse
    ).then(arrayOfPotatos => {
      return arrayOfPotatos.map((potato, index) => `${index} - ${potato}`)
    })
  })
}

result().then(arrayOfPotatos => {
  arrayOfPotatos.forEach(potato => console.log(potato))
})
```

Those two last codes does the same thing, but the second use async and await and the third does not. Async and await are just a syntax sugar to use promises.

I expect that will help you.